# undefined method `even_or_odd' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I apologize in advance. I am new to programming. I am getting the error

> undefined method `even_or_odd' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

when trying to run the following code in rails.
Any help is appreciated.

```rb
class Test
  attr_accessor :number

  def initialize(number)
    self.number = number
  end

  def even_or_odd(number)
    self.number = number

    if number % 2 == 0
      puts "Even"


    else 
      puts "Odd"
    end
  end
end

Test.assert_equals(even_or_odd(2), "Even")
```

Answer (score 2):

You've defined all of the methods in this class as instance methods, that should be called on an instance of the class (so maybe Test.find(4)) rather than the class itself (just Test). So something like this should work:

```
Test.new(4).even_or_odd(4) => true
```

However.. the way we've laid out the method with an argument means we're checking whether the argument is even / odd, rather than the test object's number. So:

```
Test.new(4).even_or_odd(5)
```

Will reset test's 'number' attribute to 5, and then check that number. I'm guessing you want to check the Test instance's number attribute rather than the argument you're supplying, so try:

```
class Test
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  def even_or_odd
    if @number % 2 == 0
      puts "Even"
    else 
      puts "Odd"
    end
  end
end
```

That will let you perform:

```
Test.new(4).even_or_odd
```

I removed the attr:accessor bit to make it a bit more obvious what is going on, but feel free to include it if you don't like calling @number every time.

Comment: Man, very cool. Ok, that helps me tremendously. Thank you, sir!